# Capacitor did not create 'resources' folder

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor

I am currently building an application using Ionic + Angular, with Capacitor for iOS & Android applications.

As mentioned in the [doc](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/android), I ran the following command to generate android and iOS platforms to the app:

```
npx cap add android
```

and

```
npx cap add ios
```

I have observed the project structure of Ionic + Capacitor applications in Github and other resources and they all have this structure:

[image]

But the app I have has something else instead.

[image]

This does not look like a good practice. Moreover, if I wanted some resources like "Splash Screen" in my application, it will require a **resources** directory. Is there a way to manage this, so I have all iOS & android related files within the **resources** directory without breaking the existing application?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every project have two android as well as IOS folders, one in the root directory which contains the platform data and one in the resources directory which contains the resources for the respective platform. The android and ios folders in the resources folder will be auto generated once you run the generate resources command. The folders you moving manually are the platform folders not the resources folders and they should be kept in the root directory of the project.

Follow [the steps to generate resources](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons)

Comment: Tried manually creating a folder and moving the "android" and "ios" folders into it. But, we get error from Capacitor afterwards, when trying to use: "npx cap open android"

Comment: Don't move the android and ios folders into it bro, just create the resources folder and put the icon.png and splash.png into it. Then run the generate resources command. Follow these steps to generate resources https://capacitorjs.com/docs/guides/splash-screens-and-icons

Comment: I understand that part. But, as I mentioned in the questioned itself, the common pattern of most projects made in Ionic is to keep the "android" and "ios" within the resouces folder. Since it looks like a good practice, I wanted to have them that way

Comment: Every project have two android as well as IOS folders, one in the root directory which contains the platform data and one in the resources directory which contains the resources for the respective platform. The android and ios folders in the resources folder will be auto generated once you run the generate resources command. The folders you moving manually are the platform folders not the resources folders and they should be kept in the root directory of the project.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it was helpful. Thank you.

Comment: If you could please edit the answer with the well-explained comment above, that would be great.